# Print the Fibonacci Sequence to the screen (5 columns of numbers per row)

Tags: processing

I an trying to print the Fibonacci sequence to the canvas. 5 numbers per row
I have calculated the Fibonacci sequence but printing 5 numbers per row to the canvas is the issue. This is what I have done so far

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
int fibonacciNumber; //the Fibonacci Number
int fibNum1; //Fibonacci Number 1
int fibNum2;// Fibonacci Number 2
final int COL_NUM = 5;
String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose the Nth Fibonacci number"); 

// collect the n Fibonacci number for the user;
void setup(){
    size(500 , 500);
}

void draw(){
    background(128);
}

void fibonacciSequance(){
    //Calculate the Fibonacci number
    fibNum1 = 0;
    fibNum2 = 1;
    for(int x=1; x<=int(n); x++){
        //if x is <= 1 ..output should be 1
        if(x <= 1){
            fibonacciNumber = fibNum2;
        }// if()
        else{
            /*
            Calculating the Fibonacci  Sequence
            */
            fibonacciNumber = fibNum1 + fibNum2;
            fibNum1 = fibNum2;
            fibNum2 =  fibonacciNumber;
        }//else()
    }//for()
}

void printSequence( ){
}
```

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue? Are there remaining questions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, if you do not understand some part of it, feel free to ask.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

int fibonacciNumber; //the Fibonacci Number
int fibNum1; //Fibonacci Number 1
int fibNum2;// Fibonacci Number 2

final int GRID_SIZE = 100;//because it is the number of numbers per row and column
String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose the Nth Fibonacci number"); 
final int FONT_SIZE = 25;

// collect the n Fibonacci number for the user;
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(128);
  textSize(FONT_SIZE);
  fibonacciSequance();
}

void fibonacciSequance() {
  //Calculate the Fibonacci number
  fibNum1 = 0;
  fibNum2 = 1;
  int x = 0;
  for (int y=0; y<int(n); y++) {
    //if x is <= 1 ..output should be 1
    if (y != 0 && y % 5 == 0)
      x++;//makes sure it does not pass the grid size
    if (y <= 1) {
      fibonacciNumber = fibNum2;
      printSequence(fibonacciNumber, x, y % 5);//prints the number on the grid
    }// if()
    else {
      /*
            Calculating the Fibonacci  Sequence
       */
      fibonacciNumber = fibNum1 + fibNum2;
      fibNum1 = fibNum2;
      fibNum2 =  fibonacciNumber;
      printSequence(fibonacciNumber, x, y % 5);//prints the number on the grid
    }//else()
  }//for()
}

void printSequence(int number, int x, int y) {
  text(number, x * GRID_SIZE + FONT_SIZE / 2, (y % 5) * GRID_SIZE + 2 * FONT_SIZE);//prints it on the grid
  //based on the font size
}
```